# NativeScript. AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/forceDarkAllowed' not found

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to run the very first NativeScript app HelloWorld that I have got from examples and I receive the message:

> AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/forceDarkAllowed' not found.

[image: The screenshot of error message]

Comment: Can you try updating the android sdk to the latest one?

Comment: I just download and install the latest version of Android SDK. No changes. Still error message.

Comment: Have you installed Android Q / API level 29 and it's build tools, compiling with same? Are you using latest CLI?

Comment: $ tns --version
6.2.0

Comment: It's work now. Was something wrong with Android SDK. I delete and reinstall it, check and change the path to SDK, and finally, the emulator started. I think that case was because of PATH in env was differ than in Android SDK settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the emulator didsn't start. And it didn't start becuase PATH in env was c:\android\sdk, but PATH in Android Studio was c:\users....\AppData....

The problem was solved by specifying the correct path to the SDK in Android Studio.

Answer (score 8):

inside App_Resources/Android/src/app.gradle

add "compileSdkVersion 29" above defaultConfig { }

will look like this :

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was because the emulator didsn't start. And it didn't start becuase PATH in env was c:\android\sdk, but PATH in Android Studio was c:\users\....\AppData\....